# Yii2 Event not run after login

Tags: yii, yii2

I created a Behavior which contains function. This function should be afterLogon of User (yii/web/User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN).
But this function never will be triggered unfortunatelly.

I have a Behaviour class for the user model:

```
class UserBehavior extends Behavior
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     * @param \yii\base\Component $owner
     */
    public function attach($owner)
    {
        parent::attach($owner);
        $owner->on(\yii\web\User::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, [$this, 'updateLoginInformation']);
    }


    /**
     * Update login information data:
     * - login ip address
     * - login time
     */
    public function updateLoginInformation()
    {
        /** @var \common\models\User $owner */
        $owner = $this->owner;
        $owner->logged_in_ip = Yii::$app->request->getUserIP();
        $owner->logged_in_at = time();
        $owner->save();
    }
}
```

I declared the events and the attach too.
But this events never be run after login...

I attached this behavior to the user model:

```
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors()
    {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
            UserBehavior::className()
        ];
    }
```

If I know well the the EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN will be triggered automatically by the Yii framework, this is the reason why I do not trigger it again.

And I do not where is the problem, because the `updageLoginInformatin` never called.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use any logic I want in a model inside the proper action that calls it (IE: actionLogin). But I like your approach.

I just made a test here and the correct way to call the event is something like this:

```
$user = \Yii::$app->user;
$user->on($user::EVENT_AFTER_LOGIN, [$this, 'updateLoginInformation']);
```

I didn't create a behavior class, I just added this lines in my `init()`, but the logic is probably the same as yours.